# SharePoint 2003 ( WSS 2.0 )

Tags: site-collection, site, 2003, wss-2.0

How to view Site Collection Url's and Site collection owners in SharePoint 2003 ( WSS 2.0 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using below stsadm command you can  view all site collections under specified web application and its owners.

```
stsadm -o enumsites -url http://web app url
```